# GSP Accessing domain class static field

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I have a domain class which contains a `Class[]` array. I want the contents of that array displayed 
using `g:select`. Although I cannot find how to access those fields. I tried `<%@page import="package.path.to.PropertyDefinition" %>`  and then

```
<g:select from="${PropertyDefinition.types}" name="cust_prop_type"/>
```

Although I am getting a very big exception of type `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException`

Is it possible to access that static Array without making use of a Controller class?

I am using version 2.3.7

```
class PropertyDefinition {

     @Transient
    public static final Class[] validTypes = [Integer.getClass(), String.getClass(), RefdataValue.getClass(), BigDecimal.getClass()]
.
.
.
```

> Exception:
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodGetParameterAnnotations(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:944)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:357)
>   at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:258)
>   at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getInterfaces(ClassNode.java:353)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.declaresInterface(ClassNode.java:945)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.implementsInterface(ClassNode.java:925)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.isDerivedFromGroovyObject(ClassNode.java:915)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.isGroovyObject(AsmClassGenerator.java:937)
>   at

Comment: don't be so shy, show us your domain class ;)

Comment: I just thought its not relevant. Adding it.

Comment: the exception you are getting can be also narrowed down to the `cause`, as `MultipleCompilationErrorsException` is saying only, that you messed-up but gives no hint on `where`

Comment: Your definition can be `@Transient static final Class[] validTypes = [Integer, String, RefdataValue, BigDecimal]` but that's probably not the issue
.

Comment: @tim_yates, the `@Transient` can be ommitted here, right?

Comment: @injecteer depends if you want the list serialised the the database with the domain class...

Comment: neither `final` nor `static` are persisted via GORM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared

```
public static final Class[] validTypes
```

in `PropertyDefinition` but you're accessing `PropertyDefinition.types` in the GSP...

Comment: Jaw dropped while reading this. The stupidity of the mistake is too damn high. http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/tumblr_lq98myTmBo1qcnum8.jpg